# How should I print acronyms and glossary entries in Latex?

Tags: texstudio, glossaries, acronyms, glossary

I hope you're having a good day. I am using LaTex (TeXstudio with MiKTeX to be precise) and want to have two distinct pages, one with acronyms and the other one with glossary entries. I have tried a lot of things but no matter what I do, I can't seem to make the acronyms appear at all in my document.

Here's what I did :

I have a main.tex, one file called acronyms.tex, a file called glossary.tex, and one called doc_config.tex.

In glossary.tex, I wrote one entry :

```
\newglossaryentry{test}
{%
    name={TEST},
    description={This is a test description},
}
```

In acronyms.tex, I have one entry too :

```
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Example}
```

In my doc_config.tex, I wrote everything to configure the glossary and more (include packages, etc)

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

Finally, in my main.tex, there are the glossary entries called in the text, the input for the pages and printglossaries :

```
\documentclass[ a4paper,
                final,
                12pt, 
                %twosides %For printing
                oneside
                ]{report}

\input{auxfiles/doc_config}

\begin{document}

\input{auxfiles/acronyms}
\input{auxfiles/glossary}

\newpage

This is an example using acronyms (\gls{ex}) and glossary entries such as \gls{test}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I also tried replacing `\printglossaries` by

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary
```

It doesn't print the acronyms and glossary, only glossary is displayed.

Could you please help me ?

Edit : I get this in my log file regarding the glossaries package.

```
Package: glossary-tree 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip65
))
\glswrite=\write3
\glo@main@file=\write4
\openout4 = `main.glo'.

Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file main.glo on input line 85.
\glo@acronym@file=\write5
\openout5 = `main.acn'.

Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file main.acn on input line 85.

(main.glsdefs) (auxfiles/acronyms.tex
\@gls@deffile=\write6
\openout6 = `main.glsdefs'.

) (auxfiles/glossary.tex) [1

\openout3 = `main.ist'.

{'MyPath'/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (main.gls) (
main.acr.tex)
[2

] (main.aux)

('MyPath'\MiKTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\gloss
ary-hypernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
)
('MyPath'\MiKTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\gloss
ary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip55
)
('MyPath'\MiKTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\gloss
ary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
```

I do run the makeglossaries command.

The .alg file says :

```
This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 23.5].
Scanning style file ./main.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file main.acn....done (1 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons).
Generating output file main.acr....done (6 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in main.acr.
Transcript written in main.alg.
```

This is the return of `\listfiles` in the log

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
auxfiles/doc_config.tex
   babel.sty    2023/05/11 v3.89 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
  french.ldf    2023/03/08 v3.5q French support from the babel system
babel-french.tex
scalefnt.sty    
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 fontenc.sty    2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
geometry.cfg
csquotes.sty    2022-09-14 v5.2n context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
csquotes.def    2022-09-14 v5.2n csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
glossaries.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
  ifthen.sty    2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
mfirstuc.sty    2022/10/14 v2.08 (NLCT)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
datatool-base.sty    2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
 amsmath.sty    2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
tracklang.sty    2022/12/13 v1.6.1 (NLCT) Track Languages
tracklang.tex    2022/12/13 v1.6.1 (NLCT) Track Languages Generic Code
translator.sty    2021-05-31 v1.12d Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
glossaries-french.ldf    2016/12/12 v1.1
glossary-hypernav.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
longtable.sty    2021-09-01 v4.17 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
glossary-super.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
    main.glsdefs
auxfiles/acronyms.tex
auxfiles/glossary.tex
    main.acr
 ***********
```

Comment: Works for me.  Could you add the log for your example document?

Comment: `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:ex} has been referenced but does not exist, rep
laced by a fixed one`
This is the part of the log file regarding the glossary, it only says that for the acronym, while it has been referenced and defined

Comment: I doubt that's the only thing in the log, the full log may be helpful.  Are you running `makeglossaries`? Do you get a `.alg` file? What does that say?

Comment: Oooh, `{'MyPath'/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (main.gls) (
main.acr.tex)` looks strange, that should be `main.acr` (and is in my log). Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the File List it adds towards the end of the log?

Comment: I added the filelist, but it shows `main.acr`

Comment: You were right!! I manually deleted the main.acr.tex file, and my acronyms magically appeared ! I have no idea where it comes from though... Anyway, thank you for your help !

Comment: Funky, yes, I can reproduce it now, somehow the `.acr.tex` is getting read when the `.acr` should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
{'MyPath'/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (main.gls) (
main.acr.tex)
```

in the log suggests that you have somehow ended up with a `main.acr.tex` file, which (for reasons I'm not sure of) is being read instead of the `main.acr` file generated by `makeglossaries`.

Delete the `main.acr.tex` and, as everything else looks correct, the `main.acr` will be sourced as `glossaries` expects.